# Email Sender of default Magento 2 order confirmation is not correct 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, smtp

After I upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7. The sender of the order confirmation is changed from sales@mydomain.com to myusername@@c59619.sgvps.net

I checked the config->sales email and general->store email addresses,there are set correctly as sales@mydomain.com.

I do not have smtp set up, i'm using default phpmailer and my hosting is siteground.

Comment: Check in your database the table 'core_config_data' is there is a value "@c59619.sgvps.net".        ```SELECT * FROM 'core_config_data' where 'value' like "%@c59619.sgvps.net%";```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found out that this is an magento core bug with 2.2.4 2.2.7 2.2.8
I reverted the following files from 2.2.6 which fixed the issue.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php
vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
```

upgraded to 2.2.9 also fixed the issue.

ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952